# Capistrano EC2 - Can't connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I am new to ssh and deploying a rails app using capistrano to EC2.  I have setup a rails environment using the CloudFormation.  I have generated a keypair in the EC2 management interface and downloaded it.  I am able ssh to my EC2 instance using the ec2-user@xxxamazonaws.com.  When I run the cap deploy:setup, terminal prompts for a Password.  I am not sure what this password is for or what I should have in my deploy.rb in order to connect.  I have spend the last 8 hours reading every blog post I can find, but it is not making much sense to me.

Comment: Just curious why not use AWS Elastic Beanstalk to deploy your rails app?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell capistrano the user you wish to connect as, and the location of your ssh key in your deploy.rb file. eg.

```
set :user, "ec2-user"
ssh_options[:keys] = %w(~/.ec2/my-secret.pem)
```

It is also very useful to put the following options in so that you can take advantage of ssh key forwarding when trying to connect to 3rd party sites like Github from your ec2 instance.

```
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```